# How to delete data from firebase and recyclerview Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, onclick

I try making program for deleting program from firebase. I use alertdialog so user can choose will delete data or not but when i try choose delete data my app get crashed. I have try some method for similar case but still not solved my case. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

My code for deleting data

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AdminStockIn, AdminViewHolder>(
                    AdminStockIn.class,
                    R.layout.row_admin_stockin_new,
                    AdminViewHolder.class,
                    DatabaseAddStock
            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder( AdminViewHolder adminViewHolder, AdminStockIn adminStockIn, int i) {

                    adminViewHolder.SetDetails(getApplicationContext(), adminStockIn.getDate(),
                            adminStockIn.getTime(), adminStockIn.getName(), adminStockIn.getQuantity(),
                            adminStockIn.getVendor(), adminStockIn.getRack());

                    adminViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AdminStockInActivity.this);
                            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.admin_stock_in_popup);

                            Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow());
                            dialog.setCancelable(true);
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                            lp.copyFrom(Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).getAttributes());
                            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

                            EditText namepop = dialog.findViewById(R.id.nameSearchPop);
                            EditText quantitypop = dialog.findViewById(R.id.inputItemQuantityPop);
                            EditText vendorpop = dialog.findViewById(R.id.inputItemVendorPop);
                            EditText rackpop = dialog.findViewById(R.id.inputItemRackPop);
                            Button updatepop = dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdateStockPop);

                            namepop.setText(adminStockIn.getName());
                            quantitypop.setText(adminStockIn.getQuantity().toString());
                            vendorpop.setText(adminStockIn.getVendor());
                            rackpop.setText(adminStockIn.getRack());

                            dialog.show();
                            updatepop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
                                    map.put("name", namepop.getText().toString());
                                    map.put("quantity", quantitypop.getText().toString());
                                    map.put("vendor", vendorpop.getText().toString());
                                    map.put("rack", rackpop.getText().toString());

                                    DatabaseAddStock.child(getRef(i).getKey()).updateChildren(map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                            Toast.makeText(AdminStockInActivity.this, "Data Have Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    })
                                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(AdminStockInActivity.this, "Data Can't Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    //Hapus file
                    adminViewHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminStockInActivity.this);
                            builder.setTitle("Hapus Barang Ini?");
                            builder.setMessage("Data tidak bisa dipulihkan setelah dihapus");

                            builder.setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    int index = i-1;
                                    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(index).removeValue();
                                    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
                                    DatabaseAddStock.child(getRef(i).getKey()).removeValue();
                                    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                                }
                            });

                            builder.setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    Toast.makeText(AdminStockInActivity.this, "Data tidak jadi dihapus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

                            builder.show();

                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    rv_item.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Here my logcat

```
2021-11-15 13:41:52.836 24724-24724/com.example.w_a_m_s_y E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.w_a_m_s_y, PID: 24724
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-2
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.ObservableSnapshotArray.get(ObservableSnapshotArray.java:165)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:185)
    at com.example.w_a_m_s_y.Admin.AdminStockFlow.AdminStockInActivity$5$2$1.onClick(AdminStockInActivity.java:348)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:174)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8043)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: int index = i-1;
                                    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(index).removeValue();
                                    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
                                    DatabaseAddStock.child(getRef(i).getKey()).removeValue();
                                    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @AlexMamo this code